# Copy records from a table on one SQL instance to an identical table on a different SQL instance

Tags: sql-server, copy

We had an intern who was given written instructions for deleting old data from a database based on dates (from within our ERP system). They were fascinated by the results and just kept deleting instead of stopping at the required date. There are now 4 years of missing records in the production database. I have these records in my development database, which is in a different instance on a different server. Is there a way to transfer just those 4 years worth of data from my development database to my production database, checking, of course, to make sure there are no duplicates (unique index on transaction number).

I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not sure where to start. I do have a test database on the same instance as the production database that I could use to test the transfer with.

Comment: Letting an intern loose on your production DB = Brave :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Assuming that this is on a different machine, you will want to create a Linked Server on your dev machine to link to the target server (Or, technically, a link from the production server to your dev machine could be used as well). Then, perform an insert of the selected records from the source to the target.

More efficiently, you can use the Export Data functionality. Right click on the database (Not the server / instance, but the database) and select Tasks / Export Data from the popup menu. This will pop up the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. Use your query above to select the data for export.

If security considerations interfere with this, create a duplicate of the table(s) with alternate names (e.g. MyInvRecords) in a new database, and export the data into those tables. Back up that DB, transfer it to someplace accessible from the target server, restore that DB, then transfer the rows back into the original DB.

I haven't had to use anything but these methods before, so one of them should work for you.

Comment: I'll try the export/import method and let you know how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. I was able to get the records over to the production machine using the export/import method. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A basic insert will work just fine.

```
Insert ProdDB.schema.YourTable
([Columns])
select ([Columns])
from TestDB.schema.YourTable
where YourDateRange predicates here
```

Comment: If there is an identity column then `set identity_insert ProdDB.schema.YourTable on` maybe required.

Comment: That appears to assume both databases are on the same server. The databases are on different servers.

Comment: Add the ServerName as part of the qualifier.... Server1.ProdDB.schema.YourTable. Depending on where you are executing the query from.

Comment: Yeah wasn't clear if they were the same instance or not. Seemed like it went back and forth. You would linked servers if different instances. In which case if they exist already using the data migration tool would be simpler.